# Minecraft Crashes when Using Command Item

Tags: java, exception, crash, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm including a simple item in my mod that, when used on an entity, should cause the game to run a command dictated by its name, here is the code:

```
        public ActionResult useOnEntity(ItemStack stack, PlayerEntity user, LivingEntity entity, Hand hand) {
        if(user.getItemCooldownManager().getCooldownProgress(this, 0) == 0){
            //user.getWorld().getServer().getCommandManager().executeWithPrefix(user.getServer().getCommandSource(), stack.getName().toString());
            user.getWorld().getServer().getCommandManager().execute(user.getWorld().getServer().getCommandManager().getDispatcher().parse(stack.getName().toString(), user.getServer().getCommandSource()), stack.getName().toString());
            //user.sendMessage(stack.getName());

            user.getItemCooldownManager().set(this, 40);
        }

        return super.useOnEntity(stack, user, entity, hand);
    }
```

I have tried both of the commented and uncommented code and both lead to the same result when I used the item on a mob, the game crashing with the error:

> Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

I don't really understand this, it seems to say that it couldn't run the client, but the client did run and only crashed when I used the item.

**UPDATE:**

After following mineblock's advice, using the "Minecraft Client" configuration the error has changed to say `Cannot invoke "net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.getCommandManager()" because the return value of "net.minecraft.world.World.getServer()" is null`. This was caused by my code calling `user.getWorld().getServer()`.

When I changed it to `user.getServer()` it said `..."net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity.getServer()" is null`

In short, if I can't use `user.getServer()` and I can't use `world.getServer()` what can I use?

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientHttpException: Status: 401

This error is harmless, it's just telling you that you're not logged into the game because you're in a development environment - you can just ignore it.

---

> Execution failed for task ':runClient'. Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

You should use your IDE's run configuration. In IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse, you should run the "Minecraft Client" configuration.

Your code has nothing to do with this error.

---

You need to check if the world is a client world or server world.

You should be returning if it is a client world:

```java
if(world.isClient) {
    return;
}
```

This needs to be done as all logic should be done on the server.

Comment: I tried swapping to the "Mincraft Client" configuration and when it told me `no module specified` I deleted .idea to fix it but the game still crashed when I used the item. However the error did change to say that `Cannot invoke "net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.getCommandManager()" because the return value of "net.minecraft.world.World.getServer()" is null`. I guess there was a error I wasn't even aware of in my configuration.